# Location of app on the Windows 7 Taskbar

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, windows-7

Is there a way to know where my application is located (in pixel) on the Windows 7 Taskbar? I am asking because I would like to show notification above the icon of my app in the Taskbar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There algorithm you ask for is described in detail on this blog: [How to find the position of a taskbar button on Windows 7 or Vista](http://blog.strixcode.com/2011/01/how-to-find-taskbar-button-position-on.html)

Answer (score 7):

While there are a number of P/Invokes available to locate an icon in the notification area, I don't think there are any to determine the location of an icon in the taskbar.

Anyway, the notification area is still there in Windows 7, so why not use a notification icon? In fact, the [Windows UX Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511448.aspx) specify this:

> - **Does your program need to display a notification?** If so, you *must* use a notification area icon.

Or if you don't need a notification balloon to display textual information of a notification, you can try using an [overlay icon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511446.aspx#overlay) instead.

Or flash the taskbar icon if it's critical that it has the user's attention.

Comment: I would've made this a comment, but the comment area doesn't give me much room to format...

Comment: No, this is an answer. Use the tools Windows already provides. Don't roll your own custom, inferior solution. Finding the pixel location of the taskbar button is nuts, and that notification is subject to breaking very easily.

Comment: I think my answer looks complete now.

Comment: I think overlay icon is the way to go. "You have new mail" "remember you are set to busy" etc. Exactly what @Martin wants to communicate.

Answer (score 2):

The way to draw the user's attention to your taskbar icon is to make it flash using the FlashWindowEx API.  http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/01/26/CSharp-Flash-Window-in-Taskbar-via-Win32-FlashWindowEx.aspx